# How to erase something drawn with NSBezierPath?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uibezierpath, nsbezierpath

I have just created a path using NSBezierPath and did [path fill] to draw it onto the view. My question is how do I remove what I have drawn?

One possible solution is to use [path fill] again with the background color but this will not work if there is a background image instead of a simple background color. So anyone has any ideas?

Comment: redraw the view a second time, but this time, don't draw it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the path from path array and call the drawRect again. btw mai know in which you are storing the paths, mutable array or dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

The path you created is displayed when you set a CALayer path

```
view.layer.path = path.CGPath;
```

To clear that path

```
view.layer.path = nil;
```